# How do I change the window that appears when I insert my pen drive?

Tags: popup, usb-drive

Basically all that has to be said has been said in the title. How do I make a window other than the default one pop up when I insert my pen drive into my PC? Can it come from a program in the USB itself as well? Not doing any actual coding yet.
Btw- if that default window with al the options has a special name plz tell me. Just so I can word my Google searches better.
Any help would be appreciated. Thx

Comment: Looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun ?

Answer (score 0):

> if that default window with al the options has a special name plz tell me

‘AutoPlay’.

> Can it come from a program in the USB itself as well?

No. An ‘Autorun’ program on the USB device will come up as one option on the AutoPlay window. The user must select it to run it.

It used to be that Autorun programs executed automatically under default settings. This was, obviously, a total security disaster. After years of flash-drive viruses this was finally disabled in Vista, leading to the current option-in-AutoPlay situation.